# Regex for not starting with specific word

Tags: php, regex, pcre2

i try to add before every word that do not have a starting `[string]:` to have `Line:` at its start so i did this regex `^(?![^:]+:)` https://regex101.com/r/oMF8ks/1

and if i write

```
1
2
3
```

it returns what i want expected

```
Line:1
Line:2
Line:3
```

and for

```
Line:1
Line:2
Line:3
```

it returns same as wanted

but my problem when i try to apply it on https://regex101.com/r/K0z3bc/1

```
1 : A
2 : B
3 : C
```

i expected

```
Line:1 : A
Line:2 : B
Line:3 : C
```

but i only got

```
1 : A
2 : B
3 : C
```

but when i change the regex to `^(?!Line:)` https://regex101.com/r/49i9tQ/1 then it works but i want it to work for all words and not just `Line`

Comment: `^(?![^\s:]+:)`

Comment: @designer132 it would not work for strings like `1:A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^([^:\s]++)(?!:)
```

and replace with `Line:$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/viGxhn/3). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^:\s]++)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `:` and whitespace (possessive quantifier prevents backtracking into the `[^:\s]` pattern and thus prevents partial matching if a colon is present further in the string)
- `(?!:)` - not immediately followed with a colon.

You may also omit the group and then use `^[^:\s]++(?!:)` and replace with `Line:$0`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/viGxhn/4).

Comment: is not there a way to check if it starts once only by this rule `([a-z]+:)` just like `(Line:)` - because the `:` can be `::` or `:::` so i would use `([a-z]+:::)`

Comment: @yvgwxgtyowvaiqndwo Do you mean `^[A-Za-z0-9]++(?!:)`?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried `^(?![^:]+:)` means: assert that to the right of the current position there are not 1 or more characters other than `:` and then match `:`

You get no right replacement for the strings like `1 : A` because the negated character class `[^:]` also matches a whitespace char.

You can exclude matching whitespace characters as well:

```
^(?![^:\s]+:)
```

See the replacements at the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/IyncvA/1).